# some texts are not visible in only android firefox browsers

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I have a very simple page [Here](http://webtcc.ir/index.aspx) created by semantic-ui. the problem is some texts specially black colored texts are not visible in android firefox browser.I have tested this with 4 different mobile phones.

This is a windows Firefox:

[image: Website in windows firefox]

And this is android Firefox:

[image: Android firefox]

Any idea what is the problem? I omitted my html code because it is too long

Comment: my first guess would be there is something wrong with font. Black is not only black, but also bold. You could start with considering font-face problem?

Comment: This is only happening in firefox mobile browsers. i think it is a bug in semantic-ui maybe

Comment: i must admit it is strange, but there is a chance it could be

Answer (score 0):

You have a setting of `font-weight: 700;` for those elements. If you erase that, the text becomes visible again. I suppose it's a font issue.

Comment: Thank you i will try and let you know.